# Run FORTRAN *.exe from Ubuntu terminal

Tags: command-line, fortran

I am trying to run a FORTRAN program in Ubuntu. Code has been compiled and the result is that I have the following 2 files:

```
sfsptest2.exe
yyVx6634XC.INP
```

These files are located in: /home/user_test/FileList

At the Ubuntu command line, I enter:

```
cd FileList/
./sfsptest2.exe yyVx6634XC.INP
```

I get

```
bash: ./sfsptest2.exe: Permission denied
```

If I use:

```
gfortran sfsptest2.exe yyVx6634XC.INP
```

I get this error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld:yyVx6634XC.INP: file format not recognized: treating like linker script
/usr/bin/ld:yyVx6634XC.INP:1: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is there a way to run this FORTRAN `.exe` file from the terminal in Ubuntu?

**EDIT:**
The `*.exe` file was produced in Windows with a FORTRAN 95 compiler.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l sfsptest2.exe`?

Comment: To extend Seth's comment, you may need to give the file execute permissions: [`chmod`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/chmod.1.html)

Comment: @Seth: the output is `-rw-r--r-- l user_test user_test 361984 Oct 2  2012 sfsptest2.exe`.

Comment: @WR Try running `chmod +x sfsptest2.exe` and then try again.

Comment: When I try `chmod +x sfsptest2.exe yyVx6634XC.INP` or `chmod +x sfsptest2.exe` it does not appear to do anything. It just returns another prompt in the terminal. It doesn't create any new files.

Comment: I am not sure if this helps but, the `*.exe` file was produced by compiling FORTRAN code in Windows with a FORTRAN 95 compiler.

Comment: @WR why would a chmod create new files? It will set execute permissions... so do the 1st command Seth posted and it should show "rwx". Then execute the program again.

Comment: @WR Yes, you won't see anything happen but it is doing things behind the scenes. Try running it again :)

Comment: Do you have the original source code of the Fortran program, or are you stuck with the version compiled for Windows? Either way, you won't be able to run it as it is.

Comment: I am stuck with the version compiled for Windows. Not even with `gfortran`?

Comment: As I understand it, `.exe` files are specific for Windows and therefore can't run natively on an Ubuntu system. So you might have luck if you run it with Wine, the Windows emulator. Or what is the program supposed to do?

Comment: Hi Seth, I ran the code 3 times, but nothing appears to have happened. I then did and `ls` before and after running but there were no new files. Is there something else I could try?

Comment: @WR: gfortran would be very helpful if you *had* the source code. But you have the digested product, and you'd be basically trying to turn a hamburger into a rare steak - you can't, you need to get the cow first :) There *are* decompilers that try to reconstruct the cow, but... let's just say it's as good a cow as you would expect from a cow made of hamburgers stitched together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to understand the following:

Your `.exe` program is **not** a FORTRAN program, it's a Windows executable, and nor Bash nor a FORTRAN compiler will understand it.

When I say that it's not a FORTRAN program *I really mean it*.

It might *have been* a FORTRAN listing on some engineer's computer, but once compiled, it is indistinguishable(*) from a Windows executable built in BASIC, Pascal or C++.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler

So the way to go here is to load it in a Windows emulator - Wine, for example:

`$ wine yourprogram.exe`

Of course you can also run it in a Windows virtual machine using VirtualBox or the virtualization environment of your choice.

*If* you can get the FORTRAN sources (and it's not overly complex or dependent on specific libraries) you might want to try to compile it under Linux.

(*) This is not *entirely* correct, but that's the gist of it unless you want to delve into the topics of reverse engineering and decompilation :)

Answer (score 1):

Your program was compiled for Windows, it won't run on Linux. Compiling is basically a way of translating the programming language that a program was written in (so, something a human understands) into a language that a computer understands. What you have here is a program that has been translated from Chinese to French (Windows) and you are trying to read it in English (Linux). That won't work.

You will either need to recompile on Linux or attempt to run it via Wine.

Comment: I have tried Wine. It runs but, (I think that) due to the difference in compiler (gfortran in Ubuntu vs something else in Windows), it is not successful. The error message points to WINE developer notes - I have already done an exhaustive search on that and the displayed messages do not lead me to anything. My only attempt left is running it in native Ubuntu and getting something to happen. Even if it is an error message it might lead me to something else. That's where I'm at.

Comment: @WR and there's no way of getting the code? That would be your best bet. Either that, or running it in a virtual machine running Windows.

Comment: @WR, no, (g)Fortran is not even in the equation. You are not dealing with compilers here, you are dealing with the finished product. It might be worth taking a shot at making it run under Wine, it could be easier than you think - but that's another AskUbuntu question :)

Comment: Thank you. I now understand the problem. My questions here have been answered. Thanks for your patience. Appreciate it.